# SQL LIKE '%...' in vba HTTP request

Tags: sql, excel, vba, salesforce, soql

I am trying to run an SOQL query to the Salesforce REST API within a macro in Excel. I am using a LIKE statement to check if there are any email addresses with the same domain, which looks like this:

```
q=SELECT+email+FROM+Contact+WHERE+email+LIKE+'%@domain.com'
```

This is just the parameter given to the HTTP request, domain being a placeholder.

**When I run the exact same request using Postman I get the correct response from the server**, however in Excel I get Error `400 bad request`.

When dropping the `%` it accepts the request, however then it obviously doesn't find any entries, as it is looking for the exact string `"@domain.com"`.

Are there any known problems with the `%`-sign within vba? Or any other suggestions what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with VBA, it is with your HTTP query. You need to escape the percent sign (`%`), which is a special characters. I guess Postman is doing this for you under the hood.

Hence, try :

```
q=SELECT+email+FROM+Contact+WHERE+email+LIKE+'%25@domain.com'
```

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character

If that's not enough for the query to succeed, you may as well escape the arobas sign (`@`):

```
q=SELECT+email+FROM+Contact+WHERE+email+LIKE+'%25%40domain.com'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was something stupid like this!

Comment: Welcome @Carl ! Sometimes 4 eyes are better than 2... Cheers !